# map response in back or front

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello I have an api that I am consuming on my backend, where I will return an array of objects (undefined quantity),

and then I map this whole result to send in as a cleaner answer

but my question is how to improve it?

I should do this map in front or back and if there is any possibility of improving this my mapping

```
   async getAllProduct(req,res){
        try {
            const listProducts= [];
            const results = await Products.findAll({
                // raw: true, <= remove
                attributes:['id','name', 'float', 'price'],
                include: [{
                    model: SubCategory,
                    as: 'subcategory',
                    attributes: ['id','name'],
                },
                {
                    model:Exteriors,
                    as: 'exteriors',
                    attributes: ['id','name']
                },
                {
                    model:Types,
                    as: 'types',
                    attributes: ['id','name']
                },
            ],
            })

            results.map( (products) => {
                const model = {
                    id: products.id,
                    name: products.name,
                    float: products.float,
                    price: products.price,
                    id_sub: products.subcategory.id,
                    subcategory: products.subcategory.name,
                    id_types: products.types.id,
                    type: products.types.name,
                    id_ext: products.exteriors.id,
                    exterior: products.exteriors.name,
                }
                listProducts.push(model);
            })
            if(listProducts){return res.status(200).json({listProducts})}
            else{return res.status(400).json({result: 'failed to get Products'})}
         } catch (error) {
             console.error(error);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize it :) you don't need to use .map only to loop and push when you can use it for both:  **.map returns and array**

```
   let listProducts= results.map( (products) => {
        return {
            id: products.id,
            name: products.name,
            float: products.float,
            price: products.price,
            id_sub: products.subcategory.id,
            subcategory: products.subcategory.name,
            id_types: products.types.id,
            type: products.types.name,
            id_ext: products.exteriors.id,
            exterior: products.exteriors.name,
        }

    })
```

(opinon based answer)I think it should be done in server, it will reduce the size of the response which will make your app faster. (if you want to save money on server cpu do it in front)

Comment: Thanks and about returning this result.
I am doing this:

return res.status (200) .json ({listProducts})

but I don't know if it's the most appropriate

Comment: Based on my opinion, it is an array :) so why return an object which contains an array just return it directly (listProducts).
BUT IT WON'T MAKE ANY DIFFERENCE, it's mostly based on the standart that a project is build (had project only objects were returned)

Answer (score 1):

Performing the mapping in the backend seems more adequate, as you’re modifying the returned object according to your own rules. If you did the mapping in the frontend, your backend will serve simply as a proxy to the API you’re consuming, and you could be calling it directly from the frontend.

Regarding optimization, you don’t need to push your objects to the array, as map already returns an array.